# 特定のコミットに対して、それが対象のブランチへ、どのマージコミットでマージされたかを判定するには？

Tags: git

あるトピックブランチ上のコミット A が、特定のブランチ B (eg. develop) へマージされているとします。

このコミットAがブランチBへマージされた際のマージコミットがどれであるかを判定したいのですが、これはどうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

---

追記: コミットAがブランチBへマージされるマージコミットとは、ブランチBからfirst parent のみを辿って得られる歴史の上で、一番最古の、コミットAの子孫であるマージコミットのことです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bash 依存になりますが、以下の方法はいかがでしょうか。
他のシェルでも、プロセス置換が行えるなら同様のことはできると思います。

```bash
grep -Fxf \
  <(git log --first-parent --merges --pretty=format:%H B; echo) \
  <(git log --ancestry-path --merges --pretty=format:%H A..B; echo) \
| tail -n 1
```

需要がありそうな要望なので、git のみでもっと簡単にできそうな気もしますが、方法を見付けられなかったので他コマンドと組み合わせました。

なお、A が B へマージされたものではなく、Bの最初の子孫から辿り着けるものだった場合、全く関係ない最古のマージコミットが結果として表示されてしまうので注意して下さい。

### 解説

上記コマンドの各断片の意味は以下の通りです。

- `grep -Fxf A B`
  ファイル A と B の共通の行を取り出すイディオム。
  ここでは A と B としてコマンドのプロセス置換を記述することにより、ふたつのコマンドの出力の共通行を取り出しています。
- `git log --first-parent --merges --pretty=format:%H B`
  Bからfirst parent のみを辿って得られるマージコミットのハッシュのみを列挙します。この後に `echo`が続いているのは、最後の出力行に付かない改行を補完するためです。
- `git log --ancestry-path --merges --pretty=format:%H A..B`
  Bとその祖先のうち、Aの子孫であるマージコミットのハッシュを列挙します。これも改行を補完するため `echo` を付けています。
- `tail -n 1`
  標準入力の最後の行を表示します。

これらを組み合わせることによって、

> Bからfirst parent のみを辿って得られる歴史の上で、一番最古の、コミットAの子孫であるマージコミット

のハッシュが得られます。

Answer (score 2):

@yoh2 さんの回答に、プロセス置換が利用できない場合や(例: msys)にも利用できるように、改善したものが次です。(かつ、もう少し汎用的な計算をしています。)

```
#!/bin/bash

CMT=$1
BR=$2

git rev-list --first-parent $CMT..$BR | {
    exec 3<&0
    {
        git rev-list --ancestry-path $CMT..$BR
        git rev-parse $CMT

    } | {

        answer=

        while read rev1 <&3; do
            while true; do
                if ! read rev2; then
                    break 2
                elif [ $rev1 = $rev2 ]
                then
                    answer=$rev1
                    break
                fi
            done
        done

        echo $answer

    }
    exec 3<&-
}
```

Comment: A→B→Cとマージされた時、`--first-parent A..C`とするとA→Bのマージコミットも含まれてしまいませんか？

Comment: @unarist そんなことは、ないのではないか、と思っていますが、何か食い違いがあるかもしれないです。

Comment: 改めて検証してみたところ確かに大丈夫そうでした。勘違いだったようです。。

Answer (score 0):

[Find merge commit which include a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8475448/3090068) というまさにこれの英語版を本家で見つけました。

一番洗練されてると思ったのは、 @robinst の回答で、

```
[alias]
    find-merge = "!sh -c 'commit=$0 && branch=${1:-HEAD} && (git rev-list $commit..$branch --ancestry-path | cat -n; git rev-list $commit..$branch --first-parent | cat -n) | sort -k2 | uniq -f1 -d | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2'"
    show-merge = "!sh -c 'merge=$(git find-merge $0 $1) && [ -n \"$merge\" ] && git show $merge'"
```

を gitconfig に追加することでした。 (そして悔しいことに、多分これは msys, つまり windows の git 環境でも利用可能だと思われます。)